How to Find accuracy of FastText model in text classification?
in machine learning, all models have the equation of accuracy while in the FastText model, we don't have please support.

The calculation of 'accuracy' for a classification model, against some set of inputs with known classes, is always the same:

run the model against each item
if its prediction matches the target class, count it as correct
accuracy is the count-of-correct divided by the total-number-of-tests

If you have trained a FastText model in its -supervised mode, and can ask it to predict labels for new texts, and you have additional texts with known correct labels, you have everything you need to do the above calculation.
Testing the accuracy against the same datapoints used to train the model will give an artificially high accuracy that may be somewhat useful as a relative measure against other design choices, but will not likely be an accurate estimate of its accuracy on other yet-to-be-seen items with other idiosyncracies the model had no chance to learn.
Testing the accuracy against a held-out set of known-class items – a 'test' or 'validation' set – generates an accuracy more likely to estimate future accuracy againt similar not-yet-seen items.
